# Process execution failed on node: callMethod

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

I'm migrating from an on-premise TFS 2010 to VSO. I get multiple of the following error:

> OpsHub-012013: Process execution failed on node: callMethod, in process definition: 'Default Integration Workflow - TFS Test to TFS Test - Shared Steps'; nested exception is : script evaluation exception

**Screenshot:**

[image: OpsHub failure log]

---

What does this error message mean and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is addressed in latest release of OVSMU (1.3.0.000) , you can download it from [Visal Studio Gallary](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2)

Comment: We have analyzed the logs and found Connection reset error which was causing above error. This can occur when 9090 port is blocked by some application , firewall or antivirus on same machine. For further avoiding the issue you can turn off firewall/antivirus on same machine or check if any application is running on 9090 port which stops TFS Service unexpectedly. Let us know if it works for you. Thanks,